# Akka Netty bind port 0

Tags: akka, netty

In my unit tests I'm spinning up a remote actor system on the localhost with port 0. I don't want tests to try to bind to a port that's in use. The relevant Akka config is:

```
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "localhost"
      port = 0
    }
  }
```

How do I ask Akka or Netty which port was bound to so that I can create a client properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just a akka beginner. Hope this example helps.

```
import akka.actor._

object HelloRemote extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("HelloRemoteSystem")
  val remoteActor = system.actorOf(Props[RemoteActor], name = "RemoteActor")
  remoteActor ! "The RemoteActor is alive"

  val port = system.asInstanceOf[ExtendedActorSystem].provider.getDefaultAddress.port.get
  println(s"RemoteActor port '$port'")
}

class RemoteActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case msg: String =>
      println(s"RemoteActor received message '$msg'")
      sender ! "Hello from the RemoteActor"
  }
}
```

Comment: depositing one up-vote until i can actually test. thanks for your answer!